# How can i take all Chrome running processes from windows cmd

Tags: google-chrome, cmd, tasklist

all i found in the net is how can i take all live processes into a txt file from windows cmd

tasklist > process.txt

I want to take only Google Chrome's running processes into a file from windows cmd . Not all the processes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
tasklist | findstr "chrome.exe" > process.txt
```